# Expected identifer

Tags: ios, xcode

Have been trying to find the error in one line of code. Return expected identifier error which has been commented out.

Can you help me to find the error? Thank you.

Sorry for the bad code formatting; don't know how to get it right here.

```
   #import "BIDAppDelegate.h"
   #import "BIDSwitchViewController.h"

   @implementation BIDAppDelegate

   @synthesize window = _window;
   @synthesize switchViewController;

   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary    *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.switchViewController = [[BIDSwitchViewController alloc]

                                 initWithNibName:@"Switch View" 
    bundle:nil];
        UIView *switchView = self.switchViewController.view;
        CGRect switchViewFrame = switchView.frame;
        switchViewFrame.origin.y += [[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height; //    Expected identifier

    switchView.frame = switchViewFrame;
                                     [self.window addSubview:switchView];

        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: The {} let you format code. And you're going to have to, because I have no idea what line you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra [ at the start of the offending statement. :`[[UIApplication sharedApplication]` should be `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`

To format code, paste it in, select it and press the {} button at the top of the question editor.

Comment: Thank you for catching that error. And thank you for explaining how formatting works. Will put it to good use!

Answer (score 1):

Cnange that line to:

```
switchViewFrame.origin.y += [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
```